# Problem with Redis to handle PHP sessions

Tags: php, apache, redis

I have a multi-server apache and load balance environment.
In Apaches, I have some vhosts and all this works very well, saving the sessions in files and using iphash with the load balance.

However, to improve load distribution I put Redis in my environment to store sessions and set up all servers to store sessions on Redis through the vhosts file in Apache.

All this worked perfectly for about 4 days, and now I had to go back to the previous scenario because I was having trouble all over the environment with apache session.

The average number of connections in this environment is around 50k. Can you give me some tips on how to improve Redis to work that way? I am reading and studying the subject, and I think of making a Cluster the Redis to test this solution.

Has anyone had this experience and can you give some tips?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to explain what _"I was having trouble all over the environment with apache session"_ actually means. It could be any number of things that all has different solutions.

Comment: Is it an option to move to a more stateless architecture instead of sharing sessions? What kind of data you need to be stored in a session?
Also what kind of issues you get with Redis?

Comment: The problem with a session happens when the user clicks to change pages, requesting authentication at all times. For example, in web commerce site be requesting the login to the users several times in the same access.

Comment: As I have microservers with the Apaches for some web services, the load distribution worked very well with Redis enabled PHP session caching. But now I have this problem.